# iOS views presentation

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, orientation

Im new with iphone programming and im facing issues with the views.

I can not respent the view properly, for example in this case. I have an ViewController with a tabbar at the bottom. This controller have other 4 controllers where i show each of them when a user clicks on the icons.

But when a new view from one of the 4 controllers appears on the main controller, i get a line   under the view. In the picture is a purple one.
When i change orientation, this empty line appears in the same place. Some times, when i enter with landscape orientation in the app, this line appears at the left.

I'm working here with IB. so, can someone point me here to the right direction? :S

On shouldAutorotateTo.. method i have YES, do i have to manage the views and change size and place every time the method is executed? 
do i have to create 2 NIB for each controller, being one for each orientation option??

edit: i changed the picture to be more clear and show other "bug".

On 1 i enter to the view on portrait orientation. change it and still having a wear line up stares. All my nibs are  on portrait orientation and 320 and 480 size.

On 2 i enter to the view on landscape but the nib loads as portrait. When i change orientation, it does not expand at it should. 
How do i fix this 2nd issue?

i don't fill like having 2 nibs per controller :S

Thx in advance !

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Short answer for Your autorotation problem:
You can either create two nibs (and switch between them, when autorotation occurs), or use just one nib. This depends on your goal. If you want to create a totally different view (like music app shows cover flow on landscape, and song on portrait) you should create two nibs.
If your view is more like the message app you could easily use just one nib. Take a look at the "Size Inspector" (5th tab in Xcode 4), the red lines guide you. The apple documentation for Xcode 4 interface builder is a good start to get you into that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

That space in your view looks like the exact height of the status bar in iOS, review your NIBs in IB to see if you have a simulated status bar for your view controllers. If you do, turn it off and you will likely see that your view is not sized right. Being that it's height is 460 rather than 480.

Comment: i set all of them off. The tab bar, nav bar and status bar. Still happening :S